# How do I load Wifi driver into MinimalCD USB drive?

Tags: boot, wireless, dell, ubuntu-minimal

**My intention**: I want to install https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD
The reason is, I don't need most of the tools that come by default. I can just install i3 and xinit and I'll feel right at home.

**The problem**: I own a Dell XPS 13 (9360) which requires the `linux-firmware` package because it has the required wifi drivers. Without that, the installation can't proceed.

**My question:** How can I customize the mini installation drive so that it loads the linux-firmware package during the installation and in doing so, recognizes my wireless card?

Thanks.

Initially posted [here](https://community.ubuntu.com/t/how-to-load-wifi-driver-into-minimalcd-usb-drive/10616)

**UPDATE**
I tried this again and took some screenshots.
I saw this when I tried to detect my network hardware:
[image]

And when I inserted a USB drive with the [linux-firmware_1.173.5_all.deb](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/linux-firmware) package (downloaded using `apt-get download linux-firmware` on an Ubuntu 18.04 machine), it showed me this:
[image]

FYI, I used this [mini.iso](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/) image.
I'm sure the package I downloaded is compatible with the Ubuntu I'm trying to install. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Download the packages with another system and use an USB to add them after installation?

Comment: I can't proceed with the installation because the Minimal CD install needs the network to continue...unless I'm missing something.